# How to check current Date is in between two dates or not In IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I am trying to find out whether current date is in between two given dates or not.First I coverted the two date into current date format i.e;2014-10-02 06:45:37 +0000

```
            NSComparisonResult result,restult2;

            NSString *startDateStr=@"10/04/2014 06:03 AM";
            NSDateFormatter *startdf=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [startdf setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a"];
            NSDate *startDate12=[startdf dateFromString:startDateStr];
            NSString *startStr=[startdf stringFromDate:startDate12];
            [startdf setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
            NSDate *startDate1=[startdf dateFromString:startStr]; //here startDate1 is nil

            NSString *endDateStr=@"10/07/2014 03:03 AM";
            NSDateFormatter *enddf=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [enddf setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a"];
            NSDate *endDate12=[enddf dateFromString:endDateStr];
            NSString *endStr=[enddf stringFromDate:endDate12];
            [enddf setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
            NSDate *endDate1=[startdf dateFromString:endStr]; //here endDate1 is nil

            NSDate *date = [NSDate date];

            BOOL isBetween=[MyViewController date:date isBetweenDate:startDate1 andDate:endDate1];

            if (isBetween)
            {
                NSLog(@"@@@@@YES");
            }

+ (BOOL)date:(NSDate*)date isBetweenDate:(NSDate*)beginDate andDate:(NSDate*)endDate
{
    if ([date compare:beginDate] == NSOrderedAscending)
        return NO;

    if ([date compare:endDate] == NSOrderedDescending)
        return NO;

    return YES;
}
```

Please give any suggestions where I am going wrong.

Thanks in Advance...!

Comment: i think the return should be YES in both cases

Comment: as startDate1 and endDate1 is nil so isBetween also nil..

Comment: Convert the dates to NSDate and compare.   The hardest part is figuring out what the return code from `compare:` really means, since the description is written in Greek and further encrypted by the latest rework of the documentation.

Comment: @HotLicks I never know which way round the `compare` return values are. Even after checking docs I have to run code examples.

Comment: @Fogmeister - Yeah, when I have to do date compares a lot I write `isBefore:` and `isAfter:` category methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing stuff in your code that is pretty much not doing anything. An `NSDate` object has no format. It has no time zone. It has no months, days, years. It is merely a point in time. When you then convert that date to a string you need to provide a format (which is what `NSDateFormatter` is for).

Change your code to something like this...

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a"];

NSString *startDateStr = @"10/04/2014 06:03 AM";
NSDate *startDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:startDateStr];

NSString *endDateStr = @"10/07/2014 03:03 AM";
NSDate *endDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:endDateStr];

NSDate *date = [NSDate date];

// use a function name that matches the convention...
if ([MyViewController isDate:date betweenStartDate:startDate andEndDate:endDate])
{
    NSLog(@"@@@@@YES");
}
```

I think your function should be fine. Just don't mess around with the dates. Once you have them stop there and use them.

Answer (score 0):

Obtain NSDate from your string and compare.
NSDate doesnt contain any format. It is just number of seconds. So you dont need to reconvert it multiple times, its error prone.
Also double check that **dateFromString:** method doesnt return nil.

Answer (score 0):

To verify, whether a date falls into defined date range, you can use *compare* method or review the following code:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDate *yesterday = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:-1*24*60*60];
NSDate *tomorrow = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:+1*24*60*60];

//first condition
if([now compare:yesterday] == NSOrderedDescending && [now compare:tomorrow] == NSOrderedAscending)
    NSLog(@"now > yesterday and now < tomorrow");
else
    NSLog(@"now is outside yesterday and tomorrow");

NSDate *weekAgo = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:-7*24*60*60];

//second condition
if([weekAgo compare:yesterday] == NSOrderedDescending && [weekAgo compare:tomorrow] == NSOrderedAscending)
    NSLog(@"weekAgo > yesterday and weekAgo < tomorrow");
else
    NSLog(@"weekAgo is outside yesterday and tomorrow");
```

First condition results to

2014-10-02 14:45:21.791 dateTest[95595:8857503] now > yesterday and now < tomorrow

Second condition results to

2014-10-02 14:45:24.425 dateTest[95595:8857503] weekAgo is outside yesterday and tomorrow

Answer (score -1):

convert both dates in milliseconds

```
long firstDate = [@(floor([startDate1 timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000)) longLongValue];
long secondDate = [@(floor([endDate1 timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000)) longLongValue];
```

and then covert also the date you want to check like this and check if that value is bigger than `firstDate` and smaller than `secondDate'